# Route multiple pages to same template, with a parameter, with Bottle or Flask

Tags: python, bottle

I'd like to route multiple pages to the sample template, with a parameter, and let the other static files to be automatically routed as well:

```
@route('/test1')
@route('/hello2')
@route('/page3')
@view('tpl/page.html')
def page():
    context = {'request': request, 'pagename': ??}
    return (context)

@route('/<filename>')
def files(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='./static/')
```

and I'd like `page.html` to display the request name:

```
<div>This is the page that was requested: {{pagename}} </div>
```

I expect here:

```
This is the page that was requested: hello2
```

How to direct multiple pages to the same template, and have access to the pagename?

I tried `str(request).split('example.com/')[1].replace('>', '')` but this is a dirty hack, I imagine there's a cleaner way to get `test1`, `hello2`, etc. from a `@route`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
@route('/test1', route_name='test1')
@route('/hello2', route_name='hello2')
@route('/page3', route_name='page3')
@view('tpl/page.html')
def page(route_name):
    context = {'request': request, 'pagename': route_name}
    return (context)
```

Flask automatically passes unmatched arguments to your route.

Comment: This works with Flask, and I thought it would work for Bottle, but it doesn't: `TypeError('page() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)',)`

Comment: It's much trickier for bottle since their route decorator actually modifies the decorated function. That makes it impossible to use the above method. I think your only option is to write a route plugin that inspects the path and passes the correct route name.